# JQuery wrapInner triggers jQuery(document).ready twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `wrapInner` function but these triggers my `jQuery(document).ready` event once again.

Is this the normal behaviour?
How can this be avoided?

Update:

```
miscellaneous : function(){
            $('#nav .active a').bind('click',function(){ return false });
            $('.type-a, .type-b, .type-c, .type-d, .type-e').append('<div class="type"></div>');
            //$('body').wrapInner('<div id="root"></div>');
            $('#content').wrap('<div id="content-wrapper"></div>');

            $('#filter .time > li').append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
            $('#filter .category li a').wrapInner('<span></span>');                 
            $('#filter .time > li > ul').hide();    
            $('#filter .time > li').live('mouseenter',function(){
                if($(this).children('ul').css('display') != 'block'){
                    $(this).children('ul').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                        $(this).css({'display':'block'});
                    });
                }
            }).live('mouseleave',function(){
                if($(this).children('ul').css('display') != 'none'){
                    $(this).children('ul').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                        $(this).css({'display':'none'});
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

If I uncomment the 4th line the following alert is shown twice. 
With the line commented the alert is shown only once.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    alert('in ready');              
    });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't triggering the ready event again. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: is the code that fires the alert a child element of the body? (yes). That means the code is being re-executed because it is being re-appended to the DOM. I suggest trying to remove the script elements before you do the wrapInner.

Comment: yes, the script is located in the footer

Comment: I modified the comment with more information.

Comment: @Kevin B I understand what you mean, any suggestions on how to handle this having in mint that I need that script in the footer ? :) ... Please post your answer so I can upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your code in a child element of the body, once you wrap the body's content with another div, scripts within the body will be re-executed. Simply remove those scripts before you use wrapInner. Removing the scripts will not affect the functionality of your page other than not causing the alert to happen twice.

```
$("body").find("script").remove().end().wrapInner("<div id='root' />");
```

Comment: alert is not the only thing in the script :)

If I could have a way to set back the script after wrapping the div my problem would be solved but I have a feeling that this complexity indicates a problem.

Comment: why does the script tag need to be there? it has already been executed. The only other reason that it would need to exist is if you are getting the html of the footer and reappending it somewhere else with the intent of re-executing the script.